# 7 segment display dimmed when off

Tags: microcontroller, esp8266, 7segmentdisplay

I have a 7 segment display with a common anode which takes around 12 V. There's a 330 Ω resistor connecting each data pin to an ESP8266. To display each number, I'm just tying the requisite pins low. The issue I'm noticing is that the segments that are off are still dimly lit when they're off.

My guess is that since 12 V are coming in and each pin on the microcontroller can only output 3.3 V, there's still current flowing through the LED's because there's too much of a voltage difference (please correct me if I'm wrong).

What are some potential solutions to this problem? I've thought about possibly using a transistor and essentially tying the data pins back to 12 V when the microcontroller emits a positive voltage. That way the voltage different would be 0.

Let me know your thoughts. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may have damaged your protection diodes (\$D_2\$ and \$D_3\$ below.) It's likely that \$D_2\$ (for each I/O pin) isn't healthy, now.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL7AsO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And yes, transistors (or an IC that has them) will be needed. The easiest method would be to reverse your logic so that emitting a **1** turns the LED segment **ON** and emitting a **0** turns it off. If that's acceptable, then a simple current sink will be fine:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEOHFz.png)</sup>

This will limit the LED segment current without taxing your I/O pin's ability to source or sink current and the always-reverse-biased BC junction of the BJT will protect your I/O pin. I'm guessing about the required display segment current -- guessing at around \$20\:\text{mA}\$. If that's not right adjust the value of the emitter resistor, appropriately. (I can't tell from your writing but if the \$330\:\Omega\$ resistor is already built into the LED display device and you can't remove it, that should still be fine.)

Comment: R1 should be between the transistors collector and the LED.  This can't work as you show it, it would raise the transistors emitter above the I/O voltage output.    20mA * 150 ohms + 0.7V  = 3.7V     A 1k resistor from I/O to base would be appropriate also (as we don't know the output impedance of that I/O....)

Comment: Bit of a newbie when it comes to electronics. Didn't even know about the protection diode. Would you mind explaining how you were able to tell it was damaged?

Comment: It's not likely damaged so long as you really had that 330 ohm resistor in series with the LED ... you're just leaking current through it.  Make the circuit described above with the changes I mention, it will work for you.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot man. Was my analysis of the voltage difference correct? Is that what was causing the issue?

Comment: The I/O can't drive high enough to turn off the LED, so that protection diode is forward biased (i.e. "on").  So current would be flowing from 12V->LED->resistor->diode->V3.3

Comment: Or alternately, if you're "high-Z"ing the output (i.e. not driving high or low, you've set it as "input"), that diode is still in-circuit.

Comment: @KyleB There's no problem. And no, in this case the resistor is exactly where it belongs. Think about it.

Comment: @periblepsis How much current's flowing through the resistor and what does Ohms law say the voltage across it would be???   Then add the 0.7V for the base Vf.   Sums to 3.7V unless I did it wrong....

Comment: @KyleB If the I/O pin sits at 3.3 V, the emitter will sit about one diode drop below that. Think about what that means.

Comment: 3.3V  - 0.7V = 2.7V.   So you've got 8mA on that LED.   Put the resistor where I said, and it's straightforward to get the desired 20mA.   I will say I was too quick to say "wont work" cuz it will, so it's not wrong.  I wouldn't say it's necessarily right either...

Comment: For sure though my friend, I am always willing to learn something new!   Just not seeing it here...

Comment: @KyleB It creates a very nice current sink. The 2.7 V will sit over the 150 ohm resistor and deliver 18 mA of collector current, independent of the collector load -- up to a point. If 18 mA is enough current to *cause* too much of a voltage drop then the collector would be driven below the base and that could be a problem. However, this doesn't appear to be the case for this load.

Comment: @KyleB The other advantage here is that the BJT is in active mode, not saturated, so the base current is very low. Which is a 'nice to have' for I/O pins. I have to assume you've never seen it done this way.

Comment: No I have not - and we literally do exactly as I described on tens of millions of products each year, maybe hundreds of millions.   Maybe it's the "up to a point" bit that gets me.  A couple milliamps of base current wasted is like peeing in a lake usually.  And it works 100% of the time, always, without fail, without tweaking, without having to consider whether there's enough drive or not.   (Alot of our EE's just copy/paste, so we avoid anything that really requires analysis...)    I'm going to have to have a good pondering of this tomorrow (it's late here).  Thanks for sharing!   Cheers!

Comment: @KyleB The problem with the method you are using comes in when the voltage rail isn't known or when it isn't well regulated. The method I propose here will deliver the same current to the LED, regardless. The method you are using will not do nearly so well in those circumstances. But there are limitations to the method here, as well. (The LED rail has to be some number of volts above the MCU rail.)

Comment: The only drawback with having the resistor on the emitter is that either the hfe of the transistors need to be nearly identical, or the base resistors need some adjustment to get really the same led current in all segments.

Comment: @datenheim This isn't a precision situation: human vision being what it is (logarithmic response.) More, there's plenty of voltage left at the emitter, so temperature variation and differences in how that affects the BJTs is well-mitigated. So there's no drawback and the transistors don't need to be matched in any way. The issue would be 20 mA with a high emitter-collector voltage which here could be 7 V and that is getting close to open air dissipation of small-signal BJTs. I'd be more concerned about that. If it were a problem I'd insert a collector resistor to soak up some power.

Comment: @periblebsis Yes, the dissipation could be also a minor "drawback". Drawbacks are not evil - nothing to be picky ;-) Some BJT types have a range of CTR given as 50...160 for example, which IMO might give a visible difference in a worst case. Indeed a collector resistor can be a good idea as you wrote.